# Send commands to enfora trakers OTA via tcp

Tags: java, c#, php, c++, tcp

I work for a company that provide service to track vehicles with gps devices, rigth now I need to find a way to send commands to an enfora devices over the air using the tcp protocol, I have tried many ways with no results unfortunately. I just can send commands via sms.

I would like to send commands to request the current position, to open doors, etc.

This is the code I use to sent AT commands to other brands and it works like a charm!

```
var toBeSend = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(msj);
tcpClient.Client.Send(toBeSend);
```

What can be the problem, anyone knows?

If anyone have a script no matter if it is in c#, Java, PHP, Python, etc. please share it with me.

Comment: is the device listening on a particular IP\PORT ?

Comment: Acctually the device get the ip provided by the celullar carrier and the port that is available and I dont know what it is untill the moment when i receive data, at this point I store the connection to reuse it later to send the commands. I configured the "Friend" ip which is the one where the devices send data and from the devices supposed to receive data as well.

Answer (score 0):

Using Netty I do this:

```
channel.write(ChannelBuffers.copiedBuffer(message, StandardCharsets.US_ASCII));
```

You have to consider that to send an AT command via TCP you have to add a header to the message and also the checksum.